# Increment operator does not work on a variable if variable is set to 0

Tags: command-line, bash

Incrementing a variable `var` works in bash when enclosed in double parentheses like `(( var++ ))`. But I have found that it fails if variable is set to 0 beforehand like `var=0`.

```
$ a=0
$ ((a++)) && echo "command succeeded" || echo "command failed"
command failed

$ a=1
$ ((a++)) && echo "command succeeded" || echo "command failed"
command succeeded
```

Can someone explain this behavior?

**Environment:**

I am using gnome-terminal on Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.5 LTS.

Comment: I think you should not really on the exit status of `((` to know if the command was working.. *>> "If the result of the expression is 0, the exit status code returned will be 1 or “false”, while the exit status code returned by a non-zero value expression will be 0 or “true”."* ([via](https://developpaper.com/functions-of-in-linux-shell-2))

Comment: Sidenote: there's more than one way to [increment a variable in Bash](/q/385528/301745). Probably the most idiomatic is to explicitly make it an integer first: `declare -i a=0` then `a+=1`.

Comment: @pLumo, it's not the exit status that's wrong, but the users' assumptions (yours, too). It works exactly like post-increment is defined, and exactly like it does in e.g. C. Though you're right in that you can't use the exit status of `(( .. ))` to see if it _worked_, since a syntax error also makes it exit with status 1. (and not e.g. 2, like `[` and `[[` do)

Comment: @pLumo, exit status code is of concern to me because script is using `trap ... ERR` and this line provokes it. I have avoided this scenario, for now, by using pre-increment as my base value is 0 for `var`. But this solution is specific to my use case. Maybe I should search for a way to bypass `trap` for such/selected statements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With credit from here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146773/why-bash-increment-n-0n-return-error

The return value of (( expression )) does not indicate an error status, but, from the bash manpage:

> ((expression))
> The expression is evaluated according to the rules described below under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION. If the value of the expression is
> non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1.
> This is exactly equivalent to let "expression".

In `((a++))`you are doing a post increment. The value of `a` is `0` so `1` is returned, after that, it is incremented.

Compare

```
$ unset a
$ ((a++)) ; echo Exitcode: $? a: $a
Exitcode: 1 a: 1
```

versus

```
$ unset a
$ ((++a)) ; echo Exitcode: $? a: $a
Exitcode: 0 a: 1
```

A pre-increment, so `a` has become `1` and `0` is returned.

Comment: Technically, the increment occurs before the return; however, the returned value is the value taken before the increment.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me (in `bash` in Ubuntu),

```
$ a=0
$ echo $((a++))
0
$ echo $((a++))
1
$ echo $((a++))
2
$ echo $((a++))
3
$ echo $a
4
```

Notice the difference with

```
$ a=0
$ echo $((++a))
1
$ echo $((++a))
2
$ echo $((++a))
3
$ echo $a
3
```

Comment: check `echo $?`.

Comment: @pLumo, echo $((a++)) prints before update, echo $((++a)) prints after update.

Comment: Arithmetic expansion does not emit an exit status does not see the connection?